# What is in the output of "getent ahosts"?

Tags: networking, glibc

What are the fields printed by `getent ahosts DOMAIN`?

The output for `getent hosts` is a simple combination of IP and hostname. The `getent ahosts` has an additional third field that is, in all my test, either `STREAM`, `DGRAM` or `RAW`.

Output for `getent hosts example.net`

```
2001:500:88:200::10 example.net
```

and for `getent ahosts example.net`

```
2001:500:88:200::10 STREAM example.net
2001:500:88:200::10 DGRAM  
2001:500:88:200::10 RAW    
192.0.43.10     STREAM 
192.0.43.10     DGRAM  
192.0.43.10     RAW
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getent ahosts` uses [`getaddrinfo()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) and extracts from the `addrinfo` struct the values of `ai_addr`, `ai_socktype`, and `ai_canonname` and prints them out in order as: **IPv4/IPv6 address**, [**socket type**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#socket.28.29), and **canonical name** (if it has one).

```
SOCK_STREAM (reliable stream-oriented service or Stream Sockets)
SOCK_DGRAM (datagram service or Datagram Sockets)
SOCK_SEQPACKET (reliable sequenced packet service), or
SOCK_RAW (raw protocols atop the network layer).
```