# getent hosts prints IPv6, getent ahosts prints IPv4

Tags: getent

Verbatim output from my terminal:

```
$ getent hosts example.org
2001:500:88:200::10 example.org
$ getent ahosts example.org
192.0.43.10     STREAM 43-10.any.icann.org
192.0.43.10     DGRAM  
192.0.43.10     RAW
```

I thought they were both (at the very least [ahosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30318/what-is-in-the-output-of-getent-ahosts)) supposed to print both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Why are these printing different address types?

```
$ uname -srvmpio
Linux 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:17:36 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit**: Looks like it might be related to [this bug report](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10859).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both `getent hosts` and `getent ahosts` can potentially print both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but they decide which address(es) to print differently (that's the point of having two different commands).

`hosts` calls [`gethostbyname2`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Names.html#index-gethostbyname2-1719) (the IPv6-supporting variant of [`gethostbyname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyname.html)). The behavior is [hard-coded](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/getent.c;h=e88356dd2b2ffb2cadc0fd1532a922dc7fc0e1c6;hb=HEAD): look up an IPv6 address, and if none exists, look up an IPv4 address.

`ahosts` calls [`getaddrinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html). This function enumerates all protocols for a given name, so it can return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the same call. What it returns is determined by the settings in [`/etc/gai.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gai.conf). Because many applications are still struggling to cope with IPv6, most distributions prefer IPv4 by default and only use IPv6 by explicit request.

Some useful reading on `ahosts` and `gai.conf` around Stack Exchange:

- [What determines whether the FQDN is interpreted as IPv6 or IPv4?](https://serverfault.com/questions/173309/what-determines-whether-the-fqdn-is-interpreted-as-ipv6-or-ipv4/177649#177649)
- [Convince apt-get *not* to use IPv6 method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method)
- [What is in the output of “getent ahosts”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30318/what-is-in-the-output-of-getent-ahosts)
- [Prefer A (IPv4) DNS lookups before AAAA(IPv6) lookups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32298/prefer-a-ipv4-dns-lookups-before-aaaaipv6-lookups)
- [How to let the browser prefer IPv6 over IPv4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9181/how-to-let-the-browser-prefer-ipv6-over-ipv4)

Comment: My system also has `ahostsv4` and `ahostsv6`, as revealed in the man page.